# CSS translate not working in IE11 on SVG g

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I want to move a group of svg elements using a `<g>` tag, but it isn't working in IE, even the latest version, although it works in all the other browsers.

Do I need to use some other way of moving a group of elements in an svg?

```css
svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

g {
  transform: translate(10px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, 0);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 20 20">
    <g>
        <circle cx=10 cy=10 r=10 />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d says it is partially supportrd..

Comment: Sorry, curtis, no chance to get this working (as of 20.02.2015) - see official ie page here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811744/ie11-bug-with-implementation-of-css-transforms-in-svg

Answer (score 39, accepted):

IE11 supports the transform attribute in SVG even though it doesn't recognize the CSS style.

Fortunately, you can simply set the attribute to match the style using JavaScript:

```js
var g = document.querySelector('g'),
    transform = getComputedStyle(g).getPropertyValue('transform');
    
g.setAttribute('transform', transform);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

g {
  transform: translate(10px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, 0);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 20 20">
  <g>
<circle cx=10 cy=10 r=10 />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Oh nice that actually converts translate into a matrix and IE likes it, thanks

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: An important note - the provided code snippet will take your css STYLE from the element and convert it to transform matrix() notation.

Answer (score 6):

if someone still needs this with jQuery this worked for me:

```
jQuery("g").each(function(){
        transform = jQuery(this).css('transform');
        console.log(transform);
        jQuery(this).attr('transform',transform);
    });
```

Comment: Works great for IE11.

Answer (score 1):

Use the transform attribute

transform="translate(10, 0)"

Works like a charm on IE.

If you want to change it on the fly, use JS

Answer (score 0):

if someone still needs this with angularjs, this worked for me:

```
.directive('ieTransform', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var elementStyleMap = $window.getComputedStyle(element[0], null);
            var transform = elementStyleMap.getPropertyValue('transform');

            element[0].setAttribute('transform', transform);
        }
    };
})
```